# Remove bad network drive

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-drive

I have network drives that can't be connected to on my windows 7 machine. 
When I try to disconnect, it says it can't because they aren't found.

How can I remove them from my menu?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it in the Registry under `HKCU\Network`.  There will be a subkey for each drive letter.

Comment: `reg delete /f HKCU\Network`

Comment: I've marked this as correct because it is normally the way to resolve this problem. It didn't fix it for me, and after a couple different troubleshooting methods I've given up. I think the problem for me stemmed from the team that converted my PC from XP to Win7 using "Windows EZ Transfer tools" Something that didn't work as it should. IMO, never use tools that have the words "easy" They lie. And OS jumping from XP to 7 should be done with manual care. Not some all-in-one automatic program.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
net use * /d /y
```

Comment: says there are no entries in the list

Comment: Try running `subst` and see if it's mapped that way.